# If then else in a map

Tags: scala, functional-programming

What is a more concise way of representing the following If then else:

```
val result = scores.map(score =>
  if (score == 0)
    ("retake", 1)
  else if (score < 0)
    ("fail", 1)
  else
    ("pass", 1)
)
```

Comment: Also move the `1` outside the control structure, it's the same in all cases

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco, can you give me some sample code?

Comment: `(if (score == 0) "retake" else if (score < 0) "fail" else "pass") -> 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pattern matching with guards

```
scores map {
  case 0 => "retake" -> 1
  case x if x < 0 => "fail" -> 1
  case _ => "pass" -> 1
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Using pattern matching:

```
val result = scores.map { 
  case 0 => ("retake", 1)
  case s if s < 0 => ("fail", 1)
  case _ => ("pass", 1)
}
```